# How does a long trip abroad change US taxes for a citizen or permanent resident?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, working-abroad

I'm a green card holder in the US and a citizen of Brazil.

I work from home in the US for an American company, with an American contract. I don't report any income in Brazil and don't receive my salary in a Brazilian bank account.

I would love to go to Brazil for 3 months per year. I understand how the taxation would work in Brazil, but I'm wondering if anything needs to change in the US? Do I need to report this trip when I file my income tax the next year, or can I just consider my taxes the same way as if I was living in the US the whole year? (ps.: I wouldn't go for more tha 180 days per year)

Comment: Would you be working for a Brazilian employer, or simply working remotely for a US employer?

Comment: US employer, working remotely

Answer (score 1):

Green card holders must declare their worldwide income on their US tax return. After declaring it, though, you won't necessarily be double taxed if you have already paid foreign tax on that income.

https://www.irs.gov/individuals/international-taxpayers/taxpayers-living-abroad